# Unit testing in CakePHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp

I'm wondering, how do you guys unit-test in CakePHP?
How do you incorporate tests in projects?
What parts of a project do you test? How do you decide which parts gets to be unit-tested?
Do you guys still get to finish the job before the deadline?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> I'm wondering, how do you guys
>   unit-test in CakePHP? How do you
>   incorporate tests in projects?

I generally  use the simpletest setup used by the Cake Core. I set up a test file for each controller and model. I generally test the output of helpers / components / behaviors if the code has complex options or the helper has a largely variable output. I find my coverage to be about 65-75% and that with even such a low degree of code coverage with my tests ( 65% of a limited subset of files is pretty weak ) I spot or fix more bugs via tests than I found and fixed correctly without.

> What
>   parts of a project do you test? How do
>   you decide which parts gets to be
>   unit-tested?

I always test all Model functions. Custom find's, paginated result sets etc. I test them for the following. Correct number of results ( from a find on fixture data ), correct resultsets ( from a find on fixture data ), correctness of the fields returned, number of results returned and a correct dataset for each custom find type. Correct pagination if I am using paginated sets on any finds, custom or otherwise.

I always test controller functions that don't result in a view being rendered. As a habit I tend to move *all* logic that isn't dedicated to settings view vars or choosing a view to render to private / protected functions in the controller or to model function calls.
This lets me test the leftover controller actions ( ones with view output ) directly. If I render a view *at all* then those functions are likely behaving fine with any issues with *what* is rendered being further up the call stack.

I test helpers for their output with particular options set. I don't always cover all permutations of the options array but when two different keys result in mutually exclusive behavior or I can check for predicatble attributes being included in my markup as a result - I test for those scenarios.

If a component takes data from somewhere and manipulates it I check the format or return data on the components functions also. Same for behaviors.

If I have a static class used somewhere I will test the functions in that class for correct return results as well as generating some forced failures or intentional error conditions. Particularly if an error results in a redirect, or data being sent down the pipe in some form. If a failure is silent or returns a default value I also check to make sure that is actually happening.

> Do you guys still get to
>   finish the job before the deadline?

The first pass deadline around here is always slightly "soft" to account for testing and any issues that crop up. I find that if you use a plain old pencil and some graph paper or a whiteboard that you can easily figure out a basic set of tests before you even write any code. With this approach you might find a project takes 25% more time up front but that over the entire lifecycle of the app you will *easily* save the 25% you spent up front by not having as many issues further down the pipeline.

---

I edited this to add in some links to look at for both actual testing techniques and as a way to get a visual sense of how they come together.

1. http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/testing-models-with-cakephp-1-2-test-suite
2. http://book.cakephp.org/view/160/Testing
3. http://debuggable.com/posts/unit-testing-in-cakephp-part-1---introduction-to-unit-testing:48102610-c5d0-4398-a010-76974834cda3
4. http://mark-story.com/nodes/view/testing-cakephp-controllers-the-hard-way

Also, I have to agree and disagree with the cake devs on writing tests. It *is* a very good idea to test anything you want to reuse - be it a single component file or a complex plugin - since you will be distributing it and the tests both show working code and are great examples of what can be done with a piece of code.

As for not testing controllers because you have to use mock objects - that is just a weak excuse not to do a little bit of tricky work that once you bother with it becomes quite a bit easier each time you do it and it really, really does cut down the error rate and gives you a *huge* increase in your own understanding of your own code.

Comment: your welcome - I didn't expect this post to get popular.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look at [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/testing-models-with-cakephp-1-2-test-suite).

I'm not very familiar with CakePHP, but I generally use PHPUnit. I use Netbeans, which integrates PHPUnit quite well (I don't know if that's an option for you). It is possible to run unit tests independent of which web framework you use.

I generally test all data source connectivity (the whole data access layer), and assure that persistence works as expected. Also, if you have any business specific logic in your application, **test it**, so that you know it actually works. I don't have any long experience in testing, but I assume that others would suggest that you test your views. Personally, I use F5 in the browser for that, hehe :). When it comes to AJAX functionality I test every single bit of it (that the request does its thing and/or retrieves the desired result).

Regarding time/deadlines, the one thing that's certain is that your project will benefit from testing. The probability for exceeding the deadline is way bigger when not using some form of testing to assure that the building blocks of your application works as you want them to. Let's say your application grows bigger (which it in most cases do), you don't have any unit tests and your application fail. How do you know where to debug, and how much more time would you use searching for the problem? The main thing to understand is that assuring that small pieces of code works is really important when you get many of those small pieces.

The time spent writing tests may seem unproductive, since it does not lead directly to functionality, but it does play a really important role over time. Look at it as a form of insurance.